# Solve $\int_1^n \exp(-s i^{-p}) i^{-p} \mathrm di=\zeta(p)\epsilon$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals, convex-optimization

Let $p>1,\epsilon>0, n>1$ and $s$ be the solution of the following equation

$$\int_1^n \exp\left(-s i^{-p}\right) i^{-p} \mathrm di=\zeta(p)\epsilon$$

How does $s$ depend on $n$ and $p$? For $p>1$, $s$ seems to grow sublinearly with $n$. Below are graphs of $s$ as a function of $n$ for $p=1.5$ and $p=1.8$.

[image]
[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-exp-integral.nb)

1. What is the limit as $n\to \infty$?
2. Is there a nice approximation for finite $n$?

**Motivation**
This is the integral approximation of the sum in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4180259/behavior-of-inverse-of-fs-frac1h-n-sum-i-1n-left1-frac1i-right), which gives a way to solve for average number of steps needed for gradient descent with learning rate 1 to decrease the objective by a factor of $1/\epsilon$ times when minimizing a quadratic with eigenvalues $\{1^{-p},2^{-p},...\}$

Comment: Is ζ(p) the Riemann Zeta function?

Comment: Yes, it is the Riemann Zeta function