# Asymptotic inversion of Generalized Exponential Integral?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, special-functions

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4192757/998), Gary gives the following small-$x$ expansion for inverse of standard exponential integral $E_1^{-1}$:

$$
E_1^{ - 1} (x) =  - \log x - \log ( - \log x) - \frac{{\log ( - \log x) - 1}}{{\log x}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{(\log ( - \log x))^2 }}{{\log ^2 x}}} \right),
$$

1. How do I derive this?
2. How can this be extended to to inverse of [generalized exponential integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19) $E_p^{-1}(x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $y\to+\infty$, the generalised exponential integral possesses the [asymptotic expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.20.E2)
$$
x=E_p (y) \sim \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - y} }}{y}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^k \frac{{(p)_k }}{{y^k }}}  = \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - y} }}{{ - y}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{ - (p)_k }}{{( - y)^k }}} 
$$
where $(p)_k$ denotes the [Pochhammer symbol](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.2#iii). Taking reciprocals
$$
\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{{E_p (y)}} \sim {\rm e}^y y\left( {1 + \frac{p}{y} - \frac{p}{{y^2 }} + \frac{{p(p + 2)}}{{y^3 }} -  \ldots } \right)
$$
as $y\to+\infty$. Employing Theorem $1$ of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1006/jsco.1994.1014) with $1/x$ in place of $x$ and $\alpha=-1$, yields
$$
E^{-1}_p(x)=y \sim  - \log x - \log ( - \log x) - \frac{{\log ( - \log x) - p}}{{\log x}} +  \ldots 
$$
as $x\to 0^+$. The cited paper provides more references on these type of asymptotic inversions.